# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 onDelete()

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

```
Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['category_id','product_id']);

    });
```

I want to create this table that connect 2 others tables that i have with a realationship of many to many.
Yes i created first product and cateries table but i still receive this warning:

```
    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `category_product` add constraint `category_product_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` () on delete cascade)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\plataforma\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:670
    666|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    667|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    668|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    669|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 670|             throw new QueryException(
    671|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    672|             );
    673|         }
    674| 

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\plataforma\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') on delete cascade' at line 1")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\plataforma\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
      PDO::prepare("alter table `category_product` add constraint `category_product_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` () on delete cascade")
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\plataforma>
```

Comment: can you also provide `categories` migration?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Laravel Eloquent handles **Many to Many** relationships in an alphabetic order pivot table. You made *category_product* which is nice. 
Your migration file should be like this.

```
 Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

In two models you have to recognize the pivot table and their foreign keys -

```
 <?PHP

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use App\Product;

 class Category extends Model
{

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'catgory_product','category_id');
    }
}
```

And in Product model should be like this

```
<?PHP

 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use App\Category;

 class Product extends Model
{

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class,'catgory_product','product_id');
    }
}
```

The [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) can give you proper insight

Comment: well i am following a udemy coruse and he did this way there was any error, i know this could be only 2 things outdated way that he is using now its not working anymore, or because of the name of the tables and that is my consurne.

Because i think class relates with tables on database with the name syntax:
for example my model Product will connect with table products, but is different in model Category will connect with categories could be that syntax failing?
Well i already saw some videos and yeah i got the same resolution as you thank you. Pls review 'category_product' in last code.

Comment: That resolution maybe works but dont create the foreign key on database.
I think that only explains the relationship to laravel but not to the database